# Tension Force of Someone Passively Leaning Against a Rope

Tags: homework-and-exercises, forces, kinematics, free-body-diagram, torque

Suppose I have a rope, and my weight is $W$. If I tie the rope to a tree and hang from it, I will apply a tension force of $W$.

But suppose that I don't have a tree, and yet I want to generate a force as close to $W$ as possible, perhaps to simulate if I really could hang from the rope without breaking it.

One way I think you could do this is by attaching the rope to a fixed point and leaning away from it. The following is my derivation, where $T$ is the tension in the rope $h$ is my height, and $h_{cm}$ is the height of my center of mass.

[image]

For most people, $h_{cm}/h \approx 0.55$, so if $\varphi$ is small, it seems I can achieve my goal by  leaning at $\theta = \tan^{-1}0.55 \approx 28.8 $ degrees.

Two questions:

(1) Is this derivation basically correct, and if so

(2) What are the significant second-order effects that would prevent tension from growing to infinity as $\theta$ approaches zero? Non-rigidity of the human body, or finite friction of my shoes against the floor? What's the order of magnitude of these effects, and can I account for them analytically?

Comment: @Bob D if it matters, this isn't a homework exercise, I need to know the answer for real life. I'm open to alternative setups that achieve the same goal stated in the first few lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To complete the analysis do a force balance on the person considering the normal force from the ground and the force of static friction from the ground and require the center of mass (CM) of the person to remain stationary under all external forces.

Check your relationship for the torque about the point of contact of the person on the ground; as $\theta$ decreases the length of the rope to the person is assumed constant, but the location of the person on the ground changes. At $\theta$ of zero the torque from tension is zero since the cross product of the tension force and the distance from the pivot point is zero. If you consider the force of friction, the person laying on the ground may pull on the rope horizontally to create tension: no torque, but tension on the rope from the person pulling on it.